# LINQ2SQL or Entity Framework or Enterprise Library?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, data-access-layer

with LINQ2SQL, Entity Framework in the market, does it make sense to use Enterprise Library data access application block to design Data Access Layer(DAL)?

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

That's like asking "Should I use a Dremel Rotary Tool or an Ingersol Rand industrial sandblasting rig?"

Can you describe what your application does and where it'll be used?

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what you are doing.

A lot of what I am writing is to existing stored procedures and other similar items.  I find that SqlHelper from the Application Blocks fits my needs quite well, and haven't been compelled to change.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using linq2sql and it is great. That said it can tie you with sql server (although there are third party implementations that enable linq 2 other database systems). Entity framework is rather new, but doesn't have the same restriction.

I recommend to go with either of those.